# Button element with onclick attribute need to be clicked twice to run the funcition

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I have this simple html structure which is a CSS rules demo box with 2 column. The left one with css rules and the right one with the result based on selected css rule.

here is the html code of the left section with a button which selects a specific css rule:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="contenitore-editor">
      <header class="testata">
        <h4 class="titolo-editor">CSS Demo: word-spacing</h4>
        <button id="reset" class="reset" type="button" onclick="resetCss('wordSpacing')">reset</button>
      </header>
      <div class="try-wrapper">
        <section class="option-list">
          <button type="button" value="0.2rem" class="option" onclick="changeStyle('wordSpacing')"><span>word-spacing: 0.2rem;</span></button>
```

once the button is clicked it fires the changeStyle() function which takes a rule as a unique parameter.

here is the Javascript function:

```
function changeStyle(regola) {
 document.querySelectorAll('.option').forEach(rule => {
    rule.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var value = this.value;
      var result = document.getElementById('result');
      result.style.[regola] = value;
    });
  });
}
```

Everithing is working but one thing only: button must be clicked twice to run the function. How can I avoid the double click? I want the button fires its function at the first click.

Thx in advance

Alex

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?

Comment: `changeStyle` function doesn't do anything with the passed value, only the event listeners the function adds use the value. Those are not fired before re-click on the button. Notice, that you're adding a new event listener to the buttons every time you click on that button with the online listener.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `changeStyle` is a click listener that creates a click listener on the same button. You can simplify your code, by only adding click listeners to all `.option` elements, and use data-* attributes to get the style and value from the element.

In order to find the elements, you need to put the script after all HTML elements, or set up a listener to listen to the DOM load event, like below:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  console.log("page is fully loaded");

  document.querySelectorAll('.option').forEach(rule => {
    rule.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const el = event.target;
      const result = document.getElementById('result');

      result.innerText = `${el.getAttribute('data-style')} ${el.getAttribute('data-value')}`;
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<section class="option-list">
  <button type="button" class="option" data-value="0.2rem" data-style="wordSpacing">word-spacing: 0.2rem;</button>
  <button type="button" class="option" data-value="00.1rem" data-style="letterSpacing">letter-spacing: 0.01rem;</button>
  <button type="button" class="option" data-value="1.2rem" data-style="fontSize">font-size: 1.2rem;</button>
</section>


<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thx Rickard for your fast reply. I have fixed my code following your solution and everything works fine now. 
thx thx thx